# Adding one WPF style property kills all other style properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a style for my WPF buttons, defined in the **main window**:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3fa9f5" />
        ...
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In an **UserControl**, I want to set the content and the background depending on a binding:

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Text123" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=IsHidden}"
                             Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="TextABC" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff1d25" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
```

**The problem:** The button in the UserControl looses all other properties it gets from the main window style (color, width, margins, ...).

I tried to let the UserControl button's style know the parent style via

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"
```

but with no result.

Comment: Have you set the BasedOn like `<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"> ..........
` ?

Comment: Yup. Exactly like this ... <Button.Style> <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="Button"> ...

Comment: The UserControl's XAML is a different scope than the MainWindow's XAML. Try to move the default Button Style to App.xaml.

Comment: That's it :-) ... do you want to post is as correct answer?

Comment: @Clemens get your points dude, well deserved for being one of the most reliably helpful folks on here, sie verdienen auch ein bier :)